# Compression not working with Azure front door

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compression, azure-front-door

I have hosted a site and added Azure front door into it. My hosted site is an ASP.NET MVC web application. On the initial load of the site, by clearing cache or for first-time users, most of the files including CSS and js loaded are compressed, but a few js files with query string, in my case the bundle js files are not getting compressed. One of the bundle files is 1.4MB and it loads the exact resource size, hence it takes too much time to load.

I have enabled Caching and compression from the Azure portal. Cant find what I am missing still, Somebody please help.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I found the solution, late to respond here. What I understood is that Azure front door would not cache and compress files which they are not authorized to. So in case of bundle files in MVC applications, we should allow authorization for such files and that can be done from the application web.config file. Here is the code that worked for me.
Paste this code inside configuration tag

```html
<location path="bundles">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Hope this would help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused because of query parameters.  We need to enable Query string caching behavior by the time of creation "Front Door"
[image]

Please select  "Use Query String"

[image]

refer: [Troubleshoot Azure Front Door common issues | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/troubleshoot-issues)

Comment: I tried this option, but it didn't work.

Comment: It should work when we opt-in for the option in front door. There may be issue with files as well, please cross check the URL path of the files which are having query parameters, if they are taking same internal time when they browse directly or not? request to share any code logic / sample URI for further research if required!

Comment: It's not basically the time to load those files, the issue is they are not getting compressed, as in the screenshot you can see the js file is loaded with the size of 1.4MB(the actual size), but if it's compressed it would come down to less than 500KB. I visited the site inside the hosted server where I found the same files are getting compressed but not from the outside server. And even tried disabling the front door, then it's getting compressed.

Comment: On this case, it was an issue with bundling where we implement on App Side not on Front Door. No configuration setups on Azure / Front Door side.